# How to display multiple plots in Atom/Juno

Tags: julia, atom-editor, plots.jl, juno-ide

Say I have

```
using Plots
pyplot()
one = plot(sin, 0:.1:2pi)
two = plot(cos, 0:.1:2pi)
```

I know can switch the displayed plot with `display`, but I want to show `one` and `two` in separate tabs in the Atom plot pane so that clicking on the left/right arrows switches between the plots. Is that possible?

Comment: that might not be implemented yet.

Comment: what about using any of the plot packages directly (without going through `Plots.jl`)?

Comment: I don't think so. I think it hasn't been implemented on the Juno side yet.